# How to draw a login procedure in BPMN

Tags: process, bpmn

For a school project we are investigating the way to complex login procedure of our local library. We are currently making a AS-IS model in BPMN but because we don't know the language very well we are a little bit confused:

Should every "Login" process have an incoming flow from a datastore? Same for "checking" if accounts are linked to each other?

What is the correct way to handle with this? Because it is a model for an application a lot connections with datastores are being made and would make the model messy if I used them everywhere.

Take a look to our draft model down here.

[image]

Comment: There's only one confusing thing in the model: why the user needs to open the activation mail for the "mijn Gent" and not for the "mijn Bibliothek". Other than that your model looks correct. This flow would be a bit easier if you used a vertical happy flow. Also, since the two register/login processes are the same I would not expand them here but here I'd just put a [register/login (database)] state and expand that process in a separate model.